# How can I get the Type from a UnaryExpression?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

I have a property defined as `Expression<Func<Kitten, object>>` which is `c => c.KittenAge`, where `KittenAge` is an `int?`

I want to get the type of this.

My code is:

```
Expression<Func<Kitten, object>> property = c => c.KittenAge;

var unaryExpression = property.Body as UnaryExpression;

if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(unaryExpression.Type) == null)
{
   // Error, must be nullable
}
```

Unfortunately, the error line is always hit because the `Type` is `System.Object`. How can I get the type of `int?` from the expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Expression<Func<Kitten, object>> property = c => c.KittenAge;
    var unaryExpression = property.Body as UnaryExpression;
    var propertyExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;

    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyExpression.Type) == null)
    {
      // Error, must be nullable
    }
```